# aggregating and pasting

Tags: python, aggregate, paste

I am beginning to move from R to Python and have a stupid question.

I have been looking for close to 5 hours to find a solution to my question.

I have the following code in R, which essentially takes the `dataframe df` and aggregates the outdates from a hospital based on unique ids. So my original table has many UIds repeated since someone may visit a hospital many times and each time they leave the hospital they have an out date. I want the UID, and all the outdates in one row. I could do this very easily with the following code in R.

```
newdf= aggregate(data = df, OutDate~UID, FUN=paste, sep="," )
```

Can anyone pray tell me how this can be accomplished in Python?

HEre's what my table looks like after using the above function in R

```
   -UID1,  10/20/2008, 11/30/2008, 1/1/1900, 1/1/1900 
   -UID2,  6/19/2010, 1/1/1900  
   -UID3,  11/17/2009   
   -UID4, 3/14/2010 ,   4/20/2010,  1/1/1900,   1/1/1900 
   -UID5,  12/12/2008,  8/27/2009,  1/1/1900
```

Ignore the dates, i just made them up. But the output needs to look like above.
Previously I had multiple UID1 rows for each of the dates in the current columns.
Now how do I do this in python.

Comment: What does `FUN=paste` do? Can you provide example input and output?

Comment: If you're moving from R to Python, you're probably going to be interested in [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: Tim, please see above. That is what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import defauldict

d = defaultdict(list)

for f in df.values():
   // Assuming the first value is the UID:
  d[f[0]].append(f)
```

Now `d` is a dictionary, where each key is the UID and the values are a list of rows from the dataframe. You can combine them into a string (like what you are doing with `paste`), like this:

```
for uid,values in d.iteritems():
   for value in values:
       print('{},{}'.format(uid,','.join(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like building a dictionary where the key is the UID and you append each outdate to the key as you loop through the data. This assumes that you are getting the data in the form of a csv file where3 each row of data is read by csv.DictReader. I make the assumption based on what you seem to show of the data file and the separators. As a result, each entry in the row (which can include in time, out time, diagnosis, etc) is keyed by the header row. I will alsao assume that you can tell how to read the data into csv processing. The quick code below shows how to generate the dictionary entries from the row once you have it in.

I show the final way the data will look followed by how it was derived.

```
data = {UID1:(out1, out2, out3), UID2:(out3, out4)}

data = {}
for d in datarow:
   uid = d[UID]
   if uid not in data.keys():
     data[uid] = ()
   out = d[OUT]
   data[uid].append(out)
```